# Solving $460=\frac{392}{\theta^2}(\theta+\sin(\theta))$

Tags: trigonometry

$$460=\frac{392}{\theta^2}(\theta+\sin(\theta)).$$

This equation came up while tutoring a high school student. They know nothing of calculus (so Taylor series is out). Can this be solved analytically for $\theta$? We ended up getting the point by graphing (about $1.44$ rads) but I'm curious to know if there are other methods.

Comment: The equation has no analytical solution, except using special functions.

Comment: It could be solved using iteration so multiply through by $\theta$ to get $\theta =\frac{392}{460\theta }(\theta + sin(\theta))$ then have $\theta_{n+1}=\frac{392}{460 \theta_n }(\theta_n + sin(\theta_n))$

Comment: I believe, there is no simple way even to count solutions without numerical calculations, like iteration, graphing or binary search. Example: $10=\frac{63}{x^2}(x+\sin x)$ has three solutions, which is not obvious without numerical investigation.